# Import is disabled in msaccess. Users not able to import table. Some Access permission issues

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have created one database in MS2007 and sent it to customer. When they try to import a table from my database to another database they are getting some access permission error.How to resolve that. There is also a workgroup for this database.

Error is like below:

"you do not have necessary permissions to use the 'db name'object. have the system administrator or the the person who created the object establish the appropriate permissions for you.

But we both login with the same id.

Comment: Please post more information. What is the exact error they are getting?

Comment: "you do not have necessary permissions to use the 'db name'object. have the system administrator or the the person who created the object establish the appropriate permissions for you.

But we both login with the same id.

Comment: same id, but is it the same workgroup file ?

Comment: yes.. same workgroup file..